# Tracking sent Triggered emails

Tags: marketing-cloud, history-tracking, triggered-send, tracking-extract

I am wondering if there is any way to track the sent triggered emails. So I would like to have a report with all subscribers that recieved the email, and what activities they did, for example if they recieved and opened the email, also if they clicked something in the email. Knowing that I tried the Triggered Sends Tracking in the Reports section but this kind of report doesn't show details about the subscriber but only presents statistics about the triggered email over a specific period.

Comment: Are the recipients Leads or Contacts?

Comment: Refer this link: https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000glyaAAA